# Disable anonymous event listener or pass params & events to non-anonymous listener

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm using the following listener to listen for swipe and touch events on mobile. It has the following signature:

```
$.fn.onSwipe = function(handlers) { // adding a jQuery prototype.
    my_element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
        handleSwipe(event, handlers.left, handlers.right, handlers.up, handlers.down);
    });
}
```

I like this because it allows me to:

```
$("foo").onSwipe({
    left: (event) => { ... }, // I can define this right here.
    right: (event) => { ... },
    up: (event) => { ... },
    down: (event) => { ... },
})
```

For `left`, `right`, and so on, I can define functions in the scope of assigning the listener while also being able see the event in the listener.

I've tried doing `event.preventDefault` in my direction handlers, but this still prevents scroll (which I'd like to enable by removing the event listener).

**Problem:**

1. I can't remove the event since it's anonymous.
2. I don't know how I would create a named function while being able to pass it in the same way such that the `addEventListner` will pass the `event` and direction handlers (like `handlers.left()`) to my `handleSwipe` event.

Note: I am not interested in using other third-party libraries.

Comment: "*I can't remove the event since it's anonymous.*" you just need a reference to the function - whether it has a name or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, one option is to attach the listeners with `.on` instead, allowing you to remove them all with `.off`, without having to save a reference to them:

```
$.fn.onSwipe = function(handlers) { // adding a jQuery prototype.
    $(this).on('touchmove', function(event) {
        handleSwipe(event, handlers.left, handlers.right, handlers.up, handlers.down);
    });
};
$.fn.offSwipe = function() {
    $(this).off('touchmove');
};
```

If you might have other `touchmove` listeners attached to the same element, then you'll need to save a reference to the created function when called. Without using jQuery (except for the `$.fn` part):

```
const handlersByElement = new Map();
$.fn.onSwipe = function(handlers) { // adding a jQuery prototype.
  const handler = function(event) {
    handleSwipe(event, handlers.left, handlers.right, handlers.up, handlers.down);
  };
  for (const elm of this) {
    handlersByElement.set(elm, handler);
    elm.addEventListener('touchmove', handler);
  }
};
$.fn.offSwipe = function() {
  for (const elm of this) {
    handlersByElement.set(elm, handler);
    elm.removeEventListener('touchmove', handlersByElement.get(elm));
  }
};
```

You can also use [event namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) with jQuery to simplify adding and removing of events without having to save a reference to them and without removing *all* events of that type, thanks @VLAZ:

```
$.fn.onSwipe = function(handlers) { // adding a jQuery prototype.
    $(this).on('touchmove.myswiper', function(event) {
        handleSwipe(event, handlers.left, handlers.right, handlers.up, handlers.down);
    });
};
$.fn.offSwipe = function() {
    $(this).off('touchmove.myswiper');
};
```

Comment: `$(this).off('touchmove');` will remove *all* event handlers. For this event that might be fine but in general it can cause problems if other code (particularly third party code) attaches other handlers for the same event and you remove them. There *is* a feature in jQuery buried somewhere among some documentation somewhere that is basically "namespaced events". Not sure what the official name is but you can use an existing event and then dot, followed by any string you want. For example `$(this).on('touchmove.mySpecialHandler'` this works like `$(this).on('touchmove'` - it attaches a handler

Comment: that will be executed when a `touchmove` event occurs *however*, you can then remove just that handler with `$(this).off('touchmove.mySpecialHandler');` - any other handlers that don't share the namespace will be left intact. Including any handlers attached for the generic non-namespaced `touchmove`. The namespace can be anything you really want and you can attach as many events for that namespace as you wish. The namespaces really help with more common events like `click` or `input`.